# Mounting an SD card automatically, without blocking system start when missing?

Tags: linux, mount

I wish to auto-mount an SD card onto my Debian (command-line only).

To have this, I have added this to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1          /media/sd       auto    defaults,user,umask=000 0 0
```

This works great, IF the card is presented during boot. Otherwise it will block the booting.

What I wish is to make:

- the system capable booting without the SD card (`/media/sd` is empty)
- the system capable booting with the SD card (`/media/sd` is mounted)
- when system booted without SD card, and later gets one inserted, mount it automatically
- when an SD card is umounted (manually), and later a new one inserted, mount it automatically

How could I tune the fstab to reach this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

To boot without SD card being present, you should try the following 2 options in fstab: `nobootwait` and/or `nofail`. Note that nobootwait might not be present on your system any ore.

For mounting SD card automatically (and unmounting), I think the only option is to write a script that makes use of the `mount` command and is polling for the info about the SD card.